# Using material-ui themes together with react-router

Tags: react-router, material-ui

I've got this app where I'm using `material-ui` together with  `react-router` and `connected-react-router`. I'm trying to just switch to the dark version of the default theme, but it doesn't work... I suspect the ThemeProvider doesn't pass the props down the tree due to the Router, but I'm not sure... Can anyone help? Thank you!

```
//... imports, etc.
const theme = createMuiTheme({
    palette: {
        type: 'dark',
    },
});

function App() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <Provider store={store}>
                <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
                        <Switch>
                            <Route path="/signin" component={SignIn} />
                            <Route path="/" component={Dashboard} />
                        </Switch>
                    </ConnectedRouter>
                </ThemeProvider>
            </Provider>
        </div>
    );
}


export default App;
```

Comment: A [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) reproducing the problem would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I have actually found the problem and it was a stupid mistake. I was actually importing `<ThemeProvider>` from `styled-components` instead from `material-ui`. When I changed the import, it worked as expected.

Comment: No stupid mistake, I had the same problem... Thanks for the fix!